# I don't understand why this is not working (javascript object for roof)

Tags: javascript, object

I wnat to make JSON string with object.

but i got some weird problem.

The object changes the previous value.

I do not know the reason..

my code is..

```
    var sStr = "L1^P1^Viscosity:vp1,L1^P2^Viscosity:vp2,L1^P3^Viscosity:vp3,L1^P4^Viscosity:vp4,L1^P5^Viscosity:vp5"

    var objChild1 = {};
    var objChild2 = {};
    var objRtn = {};

    var arrStr = sStr.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
        var arrSpe = arrStr[i].split('^');
        objChild2["" + arrSpe[2].split(':')[0] + ""] = arrSpe[2].split(':')[1];
        objChild1["" + arrSpe[1] + ""] = objChild2;
        objRtn["" + arrSpe[0] + ""] = objChild1;
    }

    var sOp = JSON.stringify(objRtn, null, 2);
```

I think the result of this logic is

```
{
  "L1": {
    "P1": {
      "Viscosity": "vp1"
    },
    "P2": {
      "Viscosity": "vp2"
    },
    "P3": {
      "Viscosity": "vp3"
    }

    ...    

  }
}
```

this.. but The result is

```
{
  "L1": {
    "P1": {
      "Viscosity": "vp5"
    },
    "P2": {
      "Viscosity": "vp5"
    },
    "P3": {
      "Viscosity": "vp5"
    }

    ...

  }
}
```

I always seem to be asking foolish questions.

But I have no one to ask.

Why is this happening?

And let me know what the key to this problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same `objChild1` and `objChild2` objects each time through the loop. You need to create new objects each time, but only when the property name is one that hasn't been created already.

```js
var sStr = "L1^P1^Viscosity:vp1,L1^P2^Viscosity:vp2,L1^P3^Viscosity:vp3,L1^P4^Viscosity:vp4,L1^P5^Viscosity:vp5";
var arrStr = sStr.split(',');
var objRtn = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
    var arrSpe = arrStr[i].split('^');
    var lnum = arrSpe[0];
    var pnum = arrSpe[1];
    var prop = arrSpe[2].split(':');
    var propname = prop[0];
    var propval = prop[1];
    if (!objRtn[lnum]) {
        objRtn[lnum] = {};
    }
    if (!objRtn[lnum][pnum]) {
        objRtn[lnum][pnum] = {};
    }
    objRtn[lnum][pnum][propname] = propval;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(objRtn, null, 2));
```

Comment: You need both of them in case you have `L1`, `L2`, etc.

Comment: oh..! ok. I understand!

Comment: I have one more question..  I create new objects each time (objChild1,  objChild2). Objects are not added to 'objRtn' but overwritten.. How to added object..?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. It actually needs to be conditional. If there's already an object for that `L#`, you need to update it, otherwise you need to create a new one.